# Sunmi L2 with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, barcode-scanner, sunmi

I have an application in Xamarin.Forms and would like to use a built-in scanner in [Sunmi L2](https://docs.sunmi.com/en/documentation/mobile-products/l2/) device to scan barcodes. Currently, I use a camera for scanning barcodes using [Zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing), but I need to use the scanner because the camera is much slower for my case. Unfortunately, the documentation is only for Java, and I found this kind of app to be not popular in Xamarin.Forms. Is there any way to implement this functionality so that I could turn on the scanner from my own code without using any 3rd app and get the result within it because I have other processes related to the result?

Comment: Most devices that have a built in laser scanner can deliver input to apps via a keyboard interface, so that they do not require any special APIs.  I have no idea if this particular device works that way, but it should be easy to test.   Alternately, you can write your own binding library for their Java API.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/

Comment: Very nice idea, thanks a lot. If I won't find any other approach I will try this.

Comment: see "4. Output Method" here: https://docs.sunmi.com/en/general-function-modules/scan/code-scanner-head-engineinfrared-scan-code/